# How to get all values in HMSET REDIS

Tags: redis

I am working on python with Redis.

How to display all 3 records in Redis with Key ColorRecord.
The Key **ColorRecord** is storing different records
I am only able to access individual records like  **HMGETALL ColorRecord:red** but i want to see all three records at once . Is there a command for this in Redis

```
HMSET ColorRecord:red Prod_Color "Red" Prod_Count 12 Prod_Price 300 Prod_Info "In Stock"
HMSET ColorRecord:blue Prod_Color "Blue" Prod_Count 8 Prod_Price 310 Prod_Info "In Stock"
HMSET ColorRecord:green Prod_Color "Blue" Prod_Count 8 Prod_Price 310 Prod_Info "In Stock"
```

I tried this but getting error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Redis does not have such command.

PS: [RediSearch](https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch), a search module for Redis, can achieve that.

Comment: Good answer, but maybe overkill for specific question? Can get/scan for key prefix.